# invoice2data: command not found

Tags: pip

I installed invoice2data using this command:

> pip install invoice2data

But when I write "invoice2data" in terminal, It shows this error:

*invoice2data: command not found*

Is there any way to use it in ubuntu 18.04.2?
My current Python version is 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the invoice2data library was installed correctly?

Run this command:

```
pip uninstall invoice2data
```

If the output is

```
 Skipping invoice2data as it is not installed
```

Then it was not installed correctly.

I wonder you needed sudo to install invoice2data correctly:

```
sudo pip install invoice2data
```

I hope it works.

Comment: I uninstalled invoice2data and reinstalled it but it didn't work. It worked when I restarted my ubuntu machine. Thanks!!!